# How to show this elementary fact about numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

As part of a proof in thermodynamics, I have arrived at the expression (which I use to define a function)
$$f(x,N) := x^{1/N} + x^{-1/N} -2$$
where $x \geq 1$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to show that this quantity is $\geq 0$ (and, on physical grounds associated with the total entropy change for this given cycle), I expect that if $x = 1$ and/or if $N \to \infty$, then  $f(x,N) = 0$. However, I am struggling to manipulate things further. Can anyone either explain how to do it and/or provide a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=x^{\frac{1}{N}}$, then you have $a+\frac1a-2$

Using the Arithmetic-geometric mean:
$$
a+\frac1a\geq 2\sqrt{a\cdot\frac1a}=2
$$
thus
$$
x^{\frac{1}{N}}+x^{-\frac{1}{N}}-2\geq 0.
$$
for all $x\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you! Where does the $x\geq 1$ requirement enter here?

Comment: That was the original condition in your post.

Comment: I agree, I guess what I'm asking is where did you use it in your proof?

Comment: This proof is valid for any positive real numbers, and it is used when we calculate the square root of a product, otherwise it wouldn't be defined.

Comment: I see, so the only requirement actually used in this proof was $x\geq 0$? This makes sense since the process I was describing can be performed with final temperature less than initial temperature too $ 0 \leq x <1$. @Luchoming

Comment: note that the inequality is strict, since when $x=0$ the function is not defined.